# PulseAudio Bug In New Update For Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, kernel, kubuntu, pulseaudio

Kubuntu 20.04 Lts Three Month Ago And Last Month I Got Update For PulseAudio And I Updated (Now I have version pulseaudio 13.99.1) But After That Always I Boot Up My System ,I Got Three Error In System Log

> Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="pci-0000_01_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.

> snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs found!

> Failed to find a working profile.

My kernel version : 5.4.0-65-generic

Comment: This is the wrong spot to report bugs. Bugs get reported elsewhere. You can find the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Thank you for taking the time to report it properly and making Ubuntu a better distro. It's truly appreciated.

Comment: sorry for my wrong type in title i cant report that to ubuntu because its show in my system log when i boot up